# Pandas sampling every nth value, or closest matching value to nth value

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I have a bit of a peculiar problem. I have a very large dataframe that I'm trying to sample.

My data looks something like this (two columns x and y):

```
x,y
1,'a'
1,'b'
1,'c'
3,'a'
3,'b'
3,'c'
6,'a'
6,'b'
6,'c'
```

I want to sample based on the value of 'x'. I'd like one sample out of every 32 x values (based on the change in x, so I want to sample once between 1 and 32, even if there is only one value of x between 1 and 32).

I wanted to do something like: `df[df['x'] % 32 == 0]`. The problem is that the values of x are not necessarily evenly spaced (they are "approximately" though, but not always -- such as in the example given). For example, if all the values of x in a particular subproblem are odd, the above sampling will return an empty dataframe. Effectively, I want to sample once every 32 'x's, or take the closest value to the 32nd value (it is acceptable to approximate closest -- for example, taking the next available value is fine) if no such value exists.

So if I had a series of X's `[0, 10, 32, 39, 64, 70, 73, 74, 97, 100, 110, 129]`, I'd like to sample the rows with x values matching `[0, 32, 64, 97, 129]`.

Ideally, I could also vectorize this operation, as the dataframes are often quite large.

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 6],
                   'y': ['a', 'b', 'c'] * 3})

x = [0, 10, 32, 39, 64, 70, 73, 74, 97, 100, 110, 129]
spacer = 32

X = pd.Series(x)
# For each value `n` in the range 0, 32, 64, ..., 129, find the index location of the 
# nearest value in X via `X.sub(n).abs().idxmin()`. Then use these index locations 
# to find the actual target values in X via `loc`.
target_vals = X.loc[[X.sub(n).abs().idxmin() 
                     for n in xrange(0, x[-1], spacer)]].tolist()  # `range` in Python 3.
>>> target_vals
[0, 32, 64, 97, 129]

# Sample the target values, taking a sample size of 1.
df[df['x'].isin(target_vals)].groupby('x').apply(lambda group: group.sample(1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically create your bins with list comprehensions then use `pd.cut` to create groups and use `groupby` with `sample(1)` to get one records for every 32 values of 'X'.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'X':np.random.randint(0, 100, 5000),'Y':np.random.choice(list('ABCDEF'),5000)})

bins = [i for i in np.arange(df.X.min(), df.X.max(), 32)] + [np.inf]

df.groupby(pd.cut(df.X,bins=bins), as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.sample(1).values)
```

Output:

```
[[15 'F']
 [51 'A']
 [90 'C']
 [98 'A']]
```